# General Grievous' cough

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Was his cough explained in the canon *Clone Wars*? I know in the 2003 version it was, but I'm unsure of the CGI *Clone Wars*. I was unable to find it on Wookieepedia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does General Grievous seem to have a persistent smoker's lung?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/why-does-general-grievous-seem-to-have-a-persistent-smokers-lung)

Comment: That question talks about Tartakovsky's non-canon 2D clone wars.

Comment: Related:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/general-grievous-what-is-he-actually?rq=1

Comment: @DVK - That's why I retracted the VTC and left the message.  That question asks about SW in general, but the answer focuses on the noncanonical CW.  I'm not sure if it's really a dupe.

Comment: maybe it's an homage to Gollum from LotR

Answer (score 8):

## He more or less obtains it in the episode "Lair of Grievous"

In the 10th episode of Season 1 of the *The Clone Wars* (the CGI canon series), Grievous has his legs chopped off by the Jedi Master Kit Fisto.

Grievous' horrific injuries are repaired by his medical droid A4-D, but he isn't the same afterwards — in particular, he develops a noticeably persistent hacking cough.

Truth be told, he seems to have a mild cough from the beginning of *The Clone Wars* (with no explanation), but it is clearly far worse after episode 10.  It seems to be something that accumulates with his injuries.

(Thanks @WadCheber for the video.)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfJgbqz_xxM